# How to change font size of the scientific notation offset

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a plot with large font size, I can change all font sizes easily except when I use scientific notations in the axis label. I have searched and tried but haven't found a way to change the size of the scientific appendix. See this figure:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Rtv9hw6.png][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwJ9r.png)

In this figure, "1e-4" is just too small compared to other texts and labels.
These codes are relevant in producing the enlarged fonts used in this figure:

```
ax.tick_params(labelsize=24)
ax.yaxis.get_major_formatter().set_powerlimits((0, 1))
ax.text(0.3,4.9e-4,'(a)',va='top',fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('$r$ (a.u.)',fontsize=24)
plt.ylabel('Probability',fontsize=24)
```

By the way, how to change "1e-4" into "x1e-4"? Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You want to change the fontsize of the `offset_text` from the `yaxis`. You can do that with this line:

```
ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(24)
```

Or equivalently:

```
ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(24)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! BTW, how to change "1e-4" into "x1e-4"?

Comment: not sure about that, sorry. You might want to ask a new question, hopefully someone who knows will see it. If you set the `text.usetex` `rcParams` to `True`, I think it changes to `x10^-4`, if that's any help to you.

Answer (score 4):

I use ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)) for changing 1e-4 to x10^-4

Comment: One small remark: call set_major_formatter before ticklabel_format, otherwise it may revert the ticks back to decimal notation.