# python-matplotlib: How to change axis scale multiplier label font size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on producing a plot for a scientific publication and the optimal format in my case requires significantly increased font sizes.

[image]

As you can see the label at the top of the axis spine (red box) is not changed according to the tick label size of the rest of the plot and I cannot find anything in the documentation on this.

Is there any solution?

EDIT: answered here [How to change font size of the scientific notation in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227595/how-to-change-font-size-of-the-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib)

Comment: This is called the “offset” and a solution is detailed at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227595/how-to-change-font-size-of-the-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib

Comment: try this: `ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(24)` or `ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(24)`