# Change fontsize of scientific notation next to colorbar (ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize() not working)

Tags: python, offset, colorbar, scientific-notation

is there any other way to change the fontsize of the scientific notation value next to the colorbar (the 10^...) other than ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(24) and ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(24) (from [How to change font size of the scientific notation in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227595/how-to-change-font-size-of-the-scientific-notation-in-matplotlib))?

I do not know why those are not working, maybe because I created a colorbar and the colorbar axes. That is the code for the colorbar axis (my whole code is too long to post).

Thanks so much!

```
    fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25, top=0.9, wspace=0.05)
    cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.02])
    fmt = mpl.ticker.ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True)
    fmt.set_powerlimits((0, 0))
    cbar = fig.colorbar(cs, cax=cbar_ax, orientation='horizontal', extend="both", format=fmt)

    ## not working
    # ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(24)
    # ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(24)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_fontsize(24)` doesn't work because `ax` refers to the figure axes. Something like below should work:

```
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=24)
cbar.ax.yaxis.get_offset_text().set_fontsize(24)
```